# Asp.net C# Uploading a image with white background

Tags: asp.net

I have a question about uploading an image with asp.net c#. Want to specify a fixed size like 800x800px. And i wanna take my image no matter what size, put into center of my 800x800 white background. Like that,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in code, you'll need quite a lot of it. First upload the image, resize it while checking for rotation. Then apply the padding and then save or display the result.

```
    public void WriteImage(string path, int width, int height)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(path);
        float ratio = bmp.Width / bmp.Height;
        SizeF newsize = new SizeF(width, height * ratio);
        Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap((int)newsize.Width, (int)newsize.Height);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newimage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is almost what i want to achieve. After converted the base64 i have to save this base64 converted red backgrounded image and im done. Thanks for your answer works amazing.

Comment: You're welcome. But depending what you want to to afterwards, it may be better to convert to byte array instead of Base64. If you want to store the image in a database or file system it's better to store the file as bytes. The Base64 is more for displaying the result.

Answer (score 1):

I can't use comments, so sorry if I misunderstand the question.

Have you tried applying the following css to your image:

```
.myWhiteBackground{
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
}

.myImage {
    position: absolute;    
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ba3sbow6/1/

I believe you would simply change the src of the image programmatically?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With your tech, its only centered an image at page. I also want this because fix the uploaded image size. with that i cant allow my page trying to load 4862x2845 image.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand, If the image is 4862x2845 you would like to shrink it down to fit inside the 800px x 800px white background?